# How to use url-retrieve to download a tar.gz file in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using el-get and failed to el-get-install color-theme. After some research I found the file `color-theme-6.6.0.tar.gz` downloaded by el-get is incomplete. The size of the one downloaded using el-get is `124853`, and the size would be `124858` if the file is downloaded by wget.

Then I found el-get is using url-retrieve to downloading packages. So I evaluated this code in `*scratch*` buffer.

```
(url-retrieve
 "http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/color-theme/color-theme-6.6.0.tar.gz"
 (lambda (s)
   (write-file "/home/jxq/data/tmp")))
```

The file `/home/jxq/data/tmp` now contains http header and body. The length of http header is `279` and the whole size is `125132`. So the file size of tar.gz it retrieved is `124853`. Where are the lost 5 bytes?

Is this a bug in url-retrieve or I'm using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to skip the HTTP headers (the documentation calls them "MIME headers") before writing:

```
(url-retrieve
 "http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/color-theme/color-theme-6.6.0.tar.gz"
 (lambda (s)
   (re-search-forward "\r?\n\r?\n")
   (write-region (point) (point-max) "/tmp/bla")))
```

This version saves the same contents as Wget.

Comment: It works! But I still don't get it. I have skipped the http headers manully. But the http body's size is not equal to 124858.

Comment: I got it. The difference is caused by `write-file` and `write-region`.

Comment: @amazingjxq I can't explain your lost five bytes, though. The difference between `write-file` and `write-region` should have been 279 bytes (the length of the HTTP header), and the CRLFCRLF boundary should be 4 bytes, not 5.